# Writing bytes to a file

Tags: c++, ifstream, ofstream

I have an array of bytes defined as :

`unsigned char * pixels = new unsigned char[pixelsLen];`

and I want write all bytes from this array to a `.bmp` file.

This is how it does not work:

```
ifstream screen ( "input.bmp", ios::binary | ios::in );
ofstream output ( "output.bmp", ios::binary | ios::out | ios::app );
output.write( ( char * )&pixels, pixelsLen );
output.close();
```

This is how it does work :

```
ifstream screen ( "input.bmp", ios::binary | ios::in );
ofstream output ( "output.bmp", ios::binary | ios::out | ios::app );
for ( size_t i = 0; i < pixelsLen; i++ ) {
    output.write( ( char * )&pixels[i], 1 );
}
output.close();
```

The question is why it works when I'm writing it byte by byte and does not work when I'm trying to write it at once ?

Comment: Looks from the second sample like `pixels` is already a pointer or array. `( char * )&pixels` odds are very good you don't want that `&` in the first sample.

Comment: Note that `&pixels` returns a pointer to pointer, why would you want that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually `&pixels` returns a pointer to pointer but [std::ostream::write](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/write/) function gets pointer. So try this:

```
ifstream screen ( "input.bmp", ios::binary | ios::in );
ofstream output ( "output.bmp", ios::binary | ios::out | ios::app );
output.write( reinterpret_cast<char *>(pixels), pixelsLen );
output.close();
```

Also try to avoid C-style casting.